# Melhor forma de fazer relacionamento de class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá, gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta de fazer relacionamento entre classes de 1..N e 1...1. Exemplo:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoID{get;set;}
    .............
}

public class ItemPedido
{
    public int ItemPedidoID{get;set;}
    public int PedidoId{get;set;}
    public int ProdutoId{get;set;}
    .........
}

public class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoId{get;set;}
    ...........
}
```

Comment: Depende, né. Você está usando algum ORM? Se sim, qual? Ou você nem quer fazer conexão com o banco de dados?

Answer (score 6):

Eu modelaria as classes da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

No caso utilizei o virtual para o exemplo, caso estivesse utilizando EF como ORM, também alterei o PedidoId e o ProdutoId para Id, só para ficar padrão.

Lembrando que neste exemplo esto mostrando Objetos de nossa aplicação, e não no Modelo de Dados (SQL).

Caso seu "ItemPedido" no banco de dados não tenha nenhuma propriedade (além do Id do Produto e do Id do Pedido), não é necessário criar um objeto intermediário no C# chamado ItemPedido, faz sentido criar este objeto caso seu ItemPedido tenha Quantidade por exemplo.

Abaixo segue um exemplo de uso em um console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new Context();

        var produto = new Produto() { Nome = "Produto 1" };
        var produto2 = new Produto() { Nome = "Produto 2" };

        context.Produtos.Add(produto);
        context.Produtos.Add(produto2);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var pedido = new Pedido() { Data = DateTime.Now };
        pedido.Produtos = new List<Produto>();
        pedido.Produtos.Add(produto);
        pedido.Produtos.Add(produto2);

        context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
        context.SaveChanges();


    }
}
```

Comment: Por que *Produto* tem uma lista de pedidos? Se a resposta é porque o mesmo produto pode constar em mais de um pedido, a modelagem correta seria ter uma classe exclusiva para representar o *produto no pedido*, que é diferente da classe do produto em si. Além disso, por que dois *SaveChanges*? Se deixar apenas o último *SaveChanges* o resultado é o mesmo, e executar de uma única vez todas as manipulações do banco de uma determinada operação é a prática mais comum.

Comment: Os dois SaveChanges foram só um exemplo, e sim, você tem razão, não precisa da coleção de Pedidos em Produtos (só precisaria se vc quiser recuperar os pedidos por produtos). Editei minha resposta de novo :)

Answer (score 2):

O início está correto. Falta agora definir as propriedades de navegação para uso pelo Entity Framework, por exemplo:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoId {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido> ItemPedidos { get; set; }
}

public class ItemPedido
{
    public int ItemPedidoId {get;set;}
    public int PedidoId {get;set;}
    public int ProdutoId {get;set;}

    // Acho que aqui deveria vir uma quantidade, certo?
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoId {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido> ItemPedidos { get; set; }
}
```

Aqui não há casos 1..0-1. Apenas 1..N e N..1, então vou inventar um caso 1..0-1.

Suponha que seu `Pedido` tenha um `PedidoEnderecoEntrega`. Ele pode existir ou não (ou seja, 0 ou 1 registro). A modelagem ficaria assim:

```
public class PedidoEnderecoEntrega
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Pedido")]
    public int PedidoId { get; set; } // É PedidoId mesmo. A chave primária também é estrangeira.

    ...
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
}
```

`Pedido` ficaria assim:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoId {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido> ItemPedidos { get; set; }
    public virtual PedidoEnderecoEntrega PedidoEnderecoEntrega { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado essa tua resposta me ajudou muito.

Comment: @AlyssonBormann Poderia me dizer por favor se está usando o Entity Framework? Ainda posso melhorar esta resposta.

Comment: to usando o Entity sim